# Unavailable in X OR Y vs. Unavailable in X and Y

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference

What is the difference these two statements:

1. It is unavailable in X or Y.
2. It is unavailable in X and Y.

Is 2) the same as saying:

3. It is neither available in X nor Y.

Lastly, are all three statements grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context. E.G.,

```
The needed range is unavailable in a ballista and wooden bolt.
```

Here, both items are needed to propel the bolt.

```
Free shipping is unavailable in Alaska and Hawaii.
Free shipping is unavailable in Alaska or Hawaii.
```

In both those sentences, the free shipping is cannot be obtained in *either* place. One might prefer the first, using "and", because the statement is true of both, but the second implies "Free shipping is unavailable [if sent] in Alaska or Hawaii." One is unlikely to be sending from both at once, so "or" *might* be considered acceptable.